# Laravel 5.2 : only route '/' works in windows iis server

Tags: php, laravel, routes

today I had a problem when I try to access my project route in windows iis server.

my application url is : `demo.example.com/testing/`

the root routing is working `'/'`, but not with the other.

for example, if I try to clicking menu with `'/home/'` route, the url will be like `demo.example.com/home'` , the `'testing'` is gone somehow.

PS : I already remove the `'public'` folder with moving all of files in public folder outside, and moving the other files into new folder.

Route example:

```
Route::get('/', 'frontend\frontController@index');

Route::get('/login', 'frontend\frontController@login');
```

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Post your full `routes.php`

Comment: check updated content above

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38123999/laravel-5-subdomain-redirected-to-homepage/38148739#38148739

Comment: Have you checked .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2):

it comes down to URL rewrites. I had the exact same issue, and I needed to add a rule in web.config:

```
<rule name="routes" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />                     
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php/{R:1}" />

                </rule>
```

from this blog post:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/iis-8-laravel-webconfig

Answer (score 1):

**I solved this error by downloading URL Rewrite 2.1 and having this in web.config.**

[image: Image of Web Platform where eyou cand download the assets.]

O meu ficheiro web.config

```
    <!--
    Rewrites requires Microsoft URL Rewrite Module for IIS
    Download: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
    Debug Help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules
-->
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not supossed to place laravel in a subfolder.
Your subdomain should directly point to the application without any further subfolders since Laravel will use absolute paths to navigate to your routes. e.g.

```
Route::get('home', ...)
```

will always navigate to yourdomain.com/home even though it actually maches yourdomain.com/laravel/home  unless you make a lot of changes to your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the login page by demo.example.com/testing/public/index.php?/login

If yes, the problem probably in your server configuration or .htaccess

I've just encountered the same problem, for me enabling mod_rewrite for apache2 fix it.

You should probably read:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#pretty-urls

[Can't route properly in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347704/cant-route-properly-in-laravel)

[Can't access URL in Laravel routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133517/cant-access-url-in-laravel-routes)

The last thing, You shouldn't do this thing below.

> PS : I already remove the 'public' folder with moving all of files in public folder outside, and moving the other files into new folder.

Stop messing with the folder structure. Do not do things you don't know!