# 404 error found using Laravel 4

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-4

I have created application in Laravel 4. It's giving URL problems. For example: 
if I used `http://example.com/login`, it's displaying a 404 error.

But if I used `http://example.com/index.php/login`, it's displaying without any error.

I want to use URL without `index.php` in that because by adding `index.php` in URL, CSS and JS files are not including in the page.

Comment: Do you have [mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2) enabled on the server?

Comment: @Samsquanch. I don't know. But If not then how to check it and how to enable it?

Comment: @Omkar
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337724/how-to-check-whether-mod-rewrite-is-enable-on-server
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021425/how-to-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-in-php

Answer (score 0):

the problem probably in your server configuration or .htaccess

I've just encountered the same problem, for me enabling mod_rewrite for apache2 fix it.

You should probably read:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#pretty-urls

[Can't route properly in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347704/cant-route-properly-in-laravel)

[Can't access URL in Laravel routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133517/cant-access-url-in-laravel-routes)